# Android : Searching youtube video from my app

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am developing an android app in which I am integrating youtube videos, what I want is user can search any youtube video from my app and that video can be played from my app only without opening youtube app, I am using youtube API but doesn't seems to find a solution for it

Comment: Which youtube API are you using ?

Comment: I have downloaded latest API from youtube doc

Comment: Can plz put the link of that API here ? So that I can see what is that ? You need to include that link with your question for complete information .

Comment: here you go https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: This API will help you to Play youtube video only ,It wil not search youtube videos .

Comment: @AndroidDev so, how should I search videos

Comment: I am giving you a very helpfull answer , It will search videos over youtube ,Plz wait .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What I want is user can search any YouTube Video from my app**

To search videos on youtube from your Android App you need to integrate **YouTube Data API** in your Android App . Using this API you can search by using a keyword/topic . Go through [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#examples) link

**Play YouTube videos in Android App :**

You can do this task using **YouTube Android Player API** . Here is the working [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/)

Comment: the blog by android hive is bit of old and I am looking for any other method to implement it, is there a better blog u can find

Comment: I agree , It is old but will be more helpfull while integrating YouTubeAndroid Player API .

Comment: First you should try with YouTube Video search .Then play that video in your app .

Comment: I have done good work on video search , so If you got any issue ,then put it here . I will help you .

Comment: Thank you very much... Can you suggest me good blog for youtube integration in my app, it will be very greatful

Comment: Do you mean Android YouTube Player API ?

Comment: kind of, because problem with androidhive tut is that, it is extending its activity from youtubeBaseActivity and I am using my api from fragment which already inherited from v4 Fragment, so I can't use his method

Comment: Try this https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/YouTubePlayerActivity it seems good library for Android YouTube Player .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95767/discussion-between-android-dev-and-ravi).